# Server responce is in json form

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send and receive data from server. For this I've used `Volley`. The code is in below. `Volley` can receive the data in `Json` format. The Server can send and receive data in `Json` format. How do I convert this Json data into a user readable `JAVA` format ?? There are about 10 methods in other class. The below class contains the methods for network calls and also interacts with the `MainActivity`.

```
public class Api_Volley {
    String data;
    String flag;
    public void my_volley_post (String url , JSONObject jsonObject , final Context context ) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url  , jsonObject , new Response.Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {

                String flag = response.toString();
                Toast.makeText( context , flag , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context , "Wrong" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        ApiVolleySingeltonClass.getInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Methods in another class:

```
  public void showAllOrderByUserId() {
        try {
            data_args.put("userId", 2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            data_action.put("action", "showAllOrderByUserId");
            data_action.put("args", data_args);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        route = "/order";
        new Api_Volley().my_volley_post(addUserUrl + route, data_action, context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Response format like this

```
public class Post {
    long id;
    Date dateCreated;
    String title;
    String author;
    String url;
    String body;
    }
```

After making request like below

```
public void my_volley_post (String url , JSONObject jsonObject , final Context context ) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url  , jsonObject , new Response.Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
         GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
         gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

// This will be your Entity

```
      Post post = gson.fromJson(response, Post.class));


        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context , "Wrong" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        ApiVolleySingeltonClass.getInstance(context).addToRequestque(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: @OsamaBillah happy coding

Answer (score 1):

1. Your can use json data like

   {"userNodes":[{"id":"1","name":"Enamul Haque"}]}
2. You can use volley like bellow

   ```
    private void doLoginAction() {


       String url_login = "http://www.lineitopkal.com/android/login.php";


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_login,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
           //pDialog.dismiss();


           try {
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
               JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("userNodes");
               for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                   String id = jo.getString("id");
                   Log.e("id ::",id);                                
                   String name = jo.getString("name");
                   Log.e("name ::",name);


               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
             }


         }
      },
     new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

           try {

               if (error instanceof TimeoutError ) {
                   //Time out error

               }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                   //net work error

               } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                   //error

               } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                   //Erroor
               } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                   //Error

               } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                   //Error

               }else{
                   //Error
               }
               //End


           } catch (Exception e) {


           }

          }
      }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
       //Post parameter like bellow
       params.put("uname", "era@gmail.com");
       params.put("pass", "123456");



        return params;
        }

     };

       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse JSON and have to show according to need:

By this you can use GSON (Its easy)
Use this Site to convert JSON to pojo classes.
[Click here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

These are the References site you can use and implement :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley